Synonym for "turn around" in the given context?
Consider the phrase,

My English used to be bad, however, between 2012-2015, I lived with American roommates and conversed with them in English. That's when the turn-around came.

Can somebody recommend similar phrases/words to turn-around in this context?
I checked a thesaurus but I am not satisfied with the words I saw, such as revamp.

It was a sudden change for the better for you to be able to speak English on a regular basis. Your skills improved rapidly. But turn-around suggests that your skills had been deteriorating when all you've said is that your English was "bad".


breakthrough Merriam-Webster
A)
a sudden advance especially in knowledge or technique
a medical breakthrough
B)
a person's first notable success — often used before another noun
a breakthrough novel
the actress's breakthrough performance


After I saw your answer, I posted the question on chatgpt, and it also recommended the same word.
